# undefined method `version' for main:Object carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, carrierwave

I have carrierwave's uploader working without applying any changes to uploaded images. Though when I comment out the `version` block in the generated uploader file I get an "undefined method `version' for main:Object" message.

version is a built in method, and based on what googled, and even a railscast video on it I should be able to just uncomment it and roll.

```
# Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [313, 344]
  end
```

What could I have going on in my codebase that would be causing an issue with carrierwave's `version` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error implicitly says that your version method not in scope of carrierwave uploader.

Your uploader should look like this.

```
class Uploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  version 'anything' do
    ....
  end
end
```

But as per error your uploader code is some thing like this:

```
class Uploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  ...
end
version 'anything' do
  ....
end
```

As your version method is not present inside uploader. Ruby considering it for main object when try to execute.

Few more thing also you need to make sure present in your code. You must have `rmagick` gem in your gemfile. You have `imagemagick` installed on your development machine.

`include CarrierWave::RMagick` uncommented in your uploader.